# How to animate the stroke width of a view

Tags: android, user-interface, android-animation, user-experience

I have an `ImageView` with the background set to a drawable.circle. The circle has thick stroke width. I would like to animate that stroke width to shrink from what it is set at to 1dp over a specified duration. If this can't be done with a drawable, I also have a customView that path's a circle with a paint.style set to Stroke. I would like to apply that animation to either the drawable.circle or the customView.

CustomCirleView:

```
public class CustomCircle extends View {

private Path path;
private Paint paint;
float customStrokeWidth = 80;


public float getCustomStrokeWidth() {
    return customStrokeWidth;
}

public void setCustomStrokeWidth(float customStrokeWidth) {
    this.customStrokeWidth = customStrokeWidth;
}


public CustomCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    path = new Path();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FC6C2B"));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(customStrokeWidth);
    path.addCircle(getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, (getMeasuredWidth()/2)-customStrokeWidth, Path.Direction.CW);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Animated Vector Drawables allow you to animate the stroke width. If need more precise control over the animation you can create and animate a custom drawable, it's more decoupled than a custom View.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this and then just draw the circle in your `onDraw` method. And please never do all the paint initialization inside the `onDraw` method as it always takes some time and the `onDraw` method should do as less as possible

```
private void init() {   
  animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "animationProgress", startVal, endVal);
  animator.setStartDelay(ANIMATION_START_DELAY);
  animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
  animator.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());

  path = new Path();
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FC6C2B"));
  paint.setStrokeWidth(customStrokeWidth);
  path.addCircle(getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight()/2, (getMeasuredWidth()/2)-customStrokeWidth, Path.Direction.CW);
}

/**
 * Is called by the {@link #animator} after an animation update
 */
protected void setAnimationProgress(float strokeWidth) {
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    postInvalidateOnAnimation();
}
```